# Thread-safe external process in ruby, plus checking exitstatus

Tags: ruby, thread-safety

I want to run a thread-safe piece of script in Ruby that calls an external program, then checks the exit status of that external program. What's the best way to do it? So far, I've been checking `$?`, but I think I'm getting a race condition with other parts of the program.

Here's some example code:

```
Thread.new do
  `external_program`
  if $?.exitstatus == 0
    # it worked.
  else
    # it didn't work.
  end
end
```

Ideally, I'd do something like

```
Process.new(`external_program`).exitstatus
```

so that the `exitstatus` was inextricably bound to *that* process, rather than the last one that happened to complete. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is the script open-source or private?

Comment: @Andrew: open source (it's my script).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although rb_last_status (aka `$?`) is a global variable, Ruby does a magic trick to make it per-thread: In `rb_thread_save_context`, it stores `rb_last_status` in the old thread's structure; `rb_thread_restore_context` sets `rb_last_status` from the saved value.  If you've got a race condition involving `$?`, it's a Ruby bug.

Comment: @Wayne - this is why I come to stackoverflow; people like you who know the background info. Thanks!!

Comment: @Peter, you're welcome.  I didn't know this until you asked and gave me a reason to dig into the source.  I like digging.